# Select row with max value with having clause

Tags: sql-server

```
create table Users
(
   ID int primary key,
   Username char(13) not null,
   Salary int,
   DepartmentID int,
   PCID int
);

insert into Users values (1, 'Jenson', 180000, 4,12);
insert into Users values (2, 'John', 161000, 2,11);
insert into Users values (3, 'Jack', 150000, 1,10);
insert into Users values (4, 'James', 150000, 3,9);
insert into Users values (5, 'Jeremy', 151000, 3,7);        

create table Departments
(
   ID int primary key,
   Name char(13) not null,
);

insert into Departments values (1, 'Programming');
insert into Departments values (2, 'Supply');
insert into Departments values (3, 'Medicine');
insert into Departments values (4, 'Economic');
insert into Departments values (5, 'Communication');

SELECT 
    s.dep_id as dep_id, s.Sum_Salary 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         d.ID AS dep_id, SUM(u.Salary) AS Sum_Salary 
     FROM
         dbo.users u
     INNER JOIN 
         Departments d ON u.DepartmentID = d.id
     GROUP BY 
         d.ID) s
```

I can select from `Department_id` and `sum_salary`

How can I select row select row with max value of sum_salary? Not using CTE or same ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TOP` and `ORDER BY` for this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    d.ID AS dep_id,
    sum(u.Salary) AS Sum_Salary
from dbo.users u
INNER JOIN Departments d ON u.DepartmentID=d.id
GROUP BY d.ID
order by Sum_Salary desc;
```

It'll return the top 1 row with maximum Sum_salary.

If you just want to find maximum sum_salary, use `MAX`:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(s.Sum_Salary)
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SUM(u.Salary) AS Sum_Salary 
     FROM
         dbo.users u
     INNER JOIN 
         Departments d ON u.DepartmentID = d.id
     GROUP BY 
         d.ID) s
```

Comment: But still the OP is asking for a `having` clause.?

Comment: Thanks. Excellent. But I do not wanna use sorting

Comment: @ifooi - Any particular reason? Because sorting will not be applied on the whole table, but only on the final grouped data. So, shouldn't be much of an issue if you are concerned about performance. Besides, to find the a top row based on some column, you'll have to use sort somewhere (either like I did or like in the other answer).

Comment: OK. what the diif between MAX and ORDER BY with TOP. I mean speed. is this same?

Comment: The purpose of the two doesn't mix. If you want just the max of total salary, use max(sum_salary). If you want all or some of the other columns for e.g. department ids etc along with the max sum_salary, use TOP.

Comment: I can use MAX function and i can find max. But purpose is find MAX and dep_id with max(sum_salary). I thought i can do it with MAX and having.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY SUM_SALARY DESC) AS RN FROM (SELECT D.ID AS DEP_ID ,SUM(U.SALARY) AS SUM_SALARY FROM DBO.USERS U
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON U.DEPARTMENTID=D.ID
GROUP BY D.ID )A 
)
SELECT SUM_SALARY,  RN
 FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

OR

```
SELECT D.ID AS DEP_ID ,SUM(U.SALARY) AS SUM_SALARY FROM DBO.USERS U
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON U.DEPARTMENTID=D.ID
GROUP BY D.ID 
HAVING SUM(U.SALARY) = (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(U.SALARY) AS SUM_SALARY FROM DBO.USERS U
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON U.DEPARTMENTID=D.ID
GROUP BY D.ID
ORDER BY  SUM_SALARY DESC)
```

Comment: I made cte answer in another way. I do not need use cte. Thank you anyway. cool.

Comment: GurV send answer with TOP first and I accept his answer.

Comment: Yes, but I add this later, There different ways. Main clause was not using CTE.

Comment: His answer use only top withount additions. short and fast